# C# Events and Delegates - How do I delay an event's subscriber from being called?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I learned about Events and Delegates, and have a simple example here:

```cs
public class Subject {
  public delegate void RandomDelegate();
  public event RandomDelegate randomEvent;
  void CallRandom() {
    if (randomEvent != null) {randomEvent();}
  }
}
```

I can just `Subject.randomEvent += randomEventHandler;`, to handle whenever randomEvent is called. However how do I go about a delayed event handler, that calls the nth time randomEvent is invoked after it has been subscribed, and deletes itself after?
I tried making a class to do it, but I'm confused.

```cs
public class DelayedHandler
{
    
    public int CurrentDelay { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int Delay { get; init; }

    public DelayedHandler(int delay)
    {
        Delay = delay;
    }

    public void Handler() // randomEvent += new DelayedHandler().Handler
    {
        if (CurrentDelay >= Delay)
        {
            // Logic
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentDelay++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do something on the nth occasion then you need a counter variable that you increment and then act when it reaches n. The question is whether you only care about the number of times the prerequisite conditions have been met or you also care about when an event handler was registered. If you only want to start counting after an event handler is registered then you need to be able to detect when an event handler is registered, which you normally can't but is possible to do.

Comment: Sounds like you may be interested in Rx (Reactive Extensions)?

Comment: I think you are already pretty close with your implementation. I'd say neither of those properties need to be public, though.  I'd also make the ctor take a callback (I guess you want to actually do something on the nth time) and a reference to the instance you registered for the event on. Then you have everything you need. Count the events and when the threshold is reached unregister, call the callback and clean up resources.

Comment: Instead of the callback, you could of course emit another event in turn.